# Install ncdf4 package: Error, nc-config not found or not executable

Tags: r, netcdf

I have tried to install `ncdf4` package. I have R version 3.1.1.

The problem seems to be finding the `nc-config`. If I Google for this specific problem, then I find people with the same problem, who solved it by installing the Debian package `libnetcdf-dev` before installing `ncdf4`.

I already installed that package but I keep having the same problem,

The error is as follows:

```
checking for nc-config... no
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error, nc-config not found or not executable.  This is a script that comes with the netcdf library, version 4.1-beta2 or later, and must be present for configuration to succeed.
```

Comment: What you can do is open a fresh terminal and do `which nc-config`. This will show you where the file is actually located in your system. If this file is indeed installed, the problem is probably that Linux installs it in a given location, and R expects it somewhere else (`/usr/local/bin` vs `/usr/bin` for example). You can try to fix the issue by adding the library containing `nc-config` to your `PATH` environment variable. Or the problem could be unrelated, e.g. 32 bit vs 64 bit.\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @PaulHiemstra mentioned in the comments, find out where your nc-config is:

> What you can do is open a fresh terminal and do `which nc-config`. This
>   will show you where the file is actually located in your system. If
>   this file is indeed installed, the problem is probably that Linux
>   installs it in a given location, and R expects it somewhere else
>   (/usr/local/bin vs /usr/bin for example). You can try to fix the issue
>   by adding the library containing *nc-config* to your PATH environment
>   variable. Or the problem could be unrelated, e.g. 32 bit vs 64 bit.\

For me, it is:

```
ubuntu@dark-horse:~$ which nc-config 
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/nc-config
```

I start with installing netcdf essentials using the below command

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-ncdf4
```

The above command should have gotten *nc-config* installed, if not try:

```
sudo apt-get install netcdf-bin
```

Now, download the *netcdf4* source

```
wget http://cirrus.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncdf/ncdf4_1.13.tar.gz
```

Now, try to do the install

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL ncdf4_1.13.tar.gz --configure-args="--with-nc-config=/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/nc-config"
```

Answer (score 33):

I was having a similar problem and these answers didn't quite work for me (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS).

I had to install the developer version using:

```
sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev
```

Comment: It works for me in the Ubuntu 18.04 and R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15).

Comment: and 19.10, 3.6.1

Comment: Contributor @Faith-Jones reports that this also works in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: That works for me on Linux Mint 20.1 “Ulyssa”! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

On CentOS 7, using `sudo yum install netcdf-devel.x86_64` in a terminal did the trick.

Comment: yum install netcdf-devel

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue, but you need to install

```
sudo apt install libgdal-dev libproj-dev libgeos-dev libudunits2-dev libnode-dev libcairo2-dev libnetcdf-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
```

This will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Using conda may a good option `conda install -c anaconda netcdf4`